# IF Not going in although statement true. (PHP)

Tags: php

When I Do an IF Statement using PHP while checking values from an XML File, It thinks that the statement is not true although it is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TacviewDebriefing Version="1.2.6">
    <Mission>
        <Title>TAPE0003</Title>
        <MissionTime>2015-06-03T00:00:00Z</MissionTime>
        <Duration>32890.02</Duration>
        <MainAircraftID>59</MainAircraftID>
    </Mission>
    <Events>
        <Event>
            <Time>32224.76</Time>
            <PrimaryObject ID="59">
                <Type>Aircraft</Type>
                <Name>F-16C Fighting Falcon</Name>
                <Pilot>Viper</Pilot>
                <Coalition>ROK/Shark</Coalition>
            </PrimaryObject>
            <Action>HasTakeOff</Action>
            <Airport ID="ICAO:LLHS">
                <Name>Hatzor AFB</Name>
            </Airport>
        </Event>
    </Events>
</TacviewDebriefing>
```

and that the sample of my code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filedir) or die("Error: Could not open file<br>");
    if(isset($xml->Mission)){
        foreach($xml->Events->Event as $value){
            $num++;
            if($xml->Mission->MainAircraftID === $value->PrimaryObject['ID']{
                echo $value->Action;
            }   
        }
    }
```

P.S: If i try to echo $value->PrimaryObject['ID']; 
and echo $xml->Mission->MainAircraftID; (Inside the foreach loop) 
it prints 59 and 59...

Comment: You're strict typing an SimpleXML Element object against your primaryObject id: `if((string) $xml->Mission->MainAircraftID === $value->PrimaryObject['ID']{`

Comment: Michael, the problem may rely on the comparison operator `===`: if one is a string and the other is a number, then it will not enter the if block (because `'59' !== 59`). Have you tried using `intval($xml->Mission->MainAircraftID) === intval($value->PrimaryObject['ID'])` or just `$xml->Mission->MainAircraftID == $value->PrimaryObject['ID']`? You are also missing the last parenthesis  from that if line...

Comment: Didn't know that lol.
if((string)$value->PrimaryObject['ID'] === (string) $xml->Mission->MainAircraftID)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i took Mark Baker's advise and made the if statement like this:
if((string)$value->PrimaryObject['ID'] === (string) $xml->Mission->MainAircraftID)
Thank you guys.

Comment: will be fun to debug when they're both returning some mix of FALSE and NULL and empty string, which all are convereted to empty strings, which this code evaluates to true/equal.. :p